# Replacement for non-interactive "chpasswd -e"?

Tags: users, passwd-file

On older Debian machines one could issue something like:

```
echo '<username>:*'|chpasswd -e
```

in order to change the password field of the user (`<username>`) to `*`.

Now I am aware of

```
passwd -d <username> && passwd -l <username>
```

to achieve a *similar* effect and set the password field to `!`. However, on some newer vanilla Ubuntu configurations (in particular 10.04 LTS) this leads to the user not being able to log into the machine anymore (for example via SSH and key) - with: `Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator.` - even though `passwd(1)` "warns" that this is possible.

Now that's exactly what I want to achieve, though. Manually changing the field in the `/etc/shadow` file from `!` to `*` fixes the issue, but there seems to be no scriptable way to achieve the same without directly fiddling with the `shadow` file (e.g. with `sed`). `chpasswd -e` used to be a convenient alternative, but that has been obviously removed.

So what I am looking for is either a variation of `passwd -l` that lets me choose the token that gets written into the file or any other kind of replacement for the **exact** functionality that `chpasswd -e` offered.

**NB:** `*` is already used for system accounts alright, and there seems to be a semantic difference to PAM or whatever between `!` and `*` in the password field.

**Also note:** on Debian 5 and 6 `chpasswd -e` works. So the functionality must have gotten stripped deliberately in Ubuntu. I tested Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04 (they don't have it), 11.04 and 11.10 have `chpasswd -e`.

Comment: Your last note is a bit confusing, are you indicating that Ubuntu {9.10, 11.04, 11.10} have `chpasswd -e` and {10.04} doesn't?

Comment: 11.04 and 11.10 have it, 9.10 and 10.04 don't.

Comment: IMHO, `sed` it until the next LTS server release comes out since it seems that 11.04+ now have it. 12.04 isn't too far off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple script like this one I just wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
if [[ -z "$USER" ]]; then
  echo "From which user should I clear the password?"
  read USER
fi
if chpasswd -e -h > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "$USER:*"|chpasswd -e
else
  passwd -d $USER
  cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.old
  USEROLD=$USER::
  USERNEW=$USER:*:
  sed -i "s/$USEROLD/$USERNEW/g" /etc/shadow.old
  cp /etc/shadow.old /etc/shadow
fi
```

The use of the script is at own risk.

Comment: +1 for the effort, though I wrote that I want to avoid any fiddling with the user database itself. I'm also going to accept for now, but may change this later if someone comes up with a clever alternative :)

Comment: @Marco: you realize that `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is *much* more portable than `/bin/bash`, right? ... there was a reason I exchanged it. It's "best practice", basically :)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED You realize that this is Ubuntu, and as such bash is in the same place. Also, `env` is in different places on different distributions, so you really haven't solved much :)

Comment: @Marco: unlike `bash`, `env` has been in the same location on various Linux distros, all BSDs, MacOS X, AIX, Solaris in various versions each. While `bash` on some systems is not `/bin` but `/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Yes, I realize it's Ubuntu, but that doesn't void a best practice :)